# The SUMIF function does not work with a specific column (the sum range column)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use the `SUMIF` function to sum a specific column on another sheet based on just one criteria.

**I have done this 1,000 times before.** The formula works for every single column except this one and I don't know why. I have tried so many things (changing the range to general or to numbers, etc.; it literally works for summing every other column except this one). The range and criteria remain the same. It is just the sum range which I am changing.

**No** idea what is going on. Please help!

Comment: *Turn it off and on again* :P

Comment: Seriously, how can we help if we have no idea about your data and your formula, apart that it is using `SUMIF`?

Comment: @A.S.H - turn what off?

Comment: =SUMIF(data!$I:$I,Summary!A11,data!$O:$O) - this works with column O...all I am doing is =SUMIF(data!$I:$I,Summary!A11,data!$N:$N) to sum column N but  just returns "0"        @A.S.H

Comment: Could it be that your data in column `N` is formatted as Text?

Comment: @A.S.H , nope..it was formatted as general as was the cell where I pasted this formula...then i changed them to the numbers format; still displaying 0...Column N contains a formula but so do the other columns which I have summed.

Comment: Still, those cells might be resulting from formulas that generate text. For instance if you have a formula like `=RIGHT("a123", 3)` you will get `123` but it will be text. check if that is the case so we can try to find a solution.

Comment: @A.S.H ... ahh i think you are right...this is the formula I have in N : =IF(M2<20,"1",IF(AND(M2>19,M2<51),"2",IF(M2>50,"3")))      ...the "1","2","3" would be the text..even though the range format of N is "General". I copied and pasted it as values in another column and changed the format to general or numbers but still doesn't sum.

Comment: Can't you change those initial formulas to generate numbers instead? Like `=IF(M2<20,1,IF(AND(M2>19,M2<51),2,IF(M2>50,3)))`... Why enclose those numbers with quotes in the first place?

Comment: @A.S.H - thanks for the help!

Comment: @A.S.H You should post an answer with a summary of what worked so the OP can select it (and others (like myself)) can upvote it.

Comment: @JYelton Thanks for your suggestion. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])` like many other functions that operate on numbers, expect the specified `sum_range` to be *numeric*. It happens that sometimes the users sees numbers in some columns but these ranges are actually Text.

This can happen in two situations:

- The data was entered as text preceded by a quote, i.e. `'100`
- The data results from a formula that generates text, i.e. `=RIGHT("a123", 3)`

In these cases SUMIF will treat these cells as text and ignore the numeric values. Unfortunately, using `VALUE(range)` in these cases won't help, because the function `SUMIF` wants a range parameter and does not accept a calculated array.

This was the case with the OP's range in question: column N was generated by the formula:

```
=IF(M2<20,"1",IF(AND(M2>19,M2<51),"2",IF(M2>50,"3")))
```

and the solution was to change the initial formula so that it generates numbers instead of texts, by removing the useless double-quotes around the numbers:

```
=IF(M2<20,1,IF(AND(M2>19,M2<51),2,IF(M2>50,3)))
```